# Solve Triangle using Cosine in Python

Tags: python, geometry, trigonometry, angle

Hi I'm new here and I dont really understand python or code in general but I'm trying and I been trying for 2-3 hours and I'm trying to

"Consider a triangle with sides of length 3, 7, and 9. The law of cosines states that given three sides of a triangle (a, b, and c) and angle C between sides a and b: 
 c^2 = b^2 +a^2 - 2 * a * b * cos(C)
Write Python code to calculate the three angles in the triangle."

This is a home work assignment and this is HARD!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
Heres what I done so far...

```
  import math

  a_float = 3 
  b_float = 7 
  c_float = 9

  def find_angle_cosine_of_c_float =

 (c_float**2-b_float**2-a_float**2)/(-2*a_float*b_float)

  a = input("enter A: ") 
  b = input("enter B: ") 
  c = input("enter C: ")

  angle_c_float = math.acos(cosine_of_float)

  angle_c_float = angle_c_float*180/math.pi

  assert find_angle_cosine_of_c_float(7, 9, 3)
  assert find_angle_cosine_of_c_float(3, 7, 9) 
  assert find_angle_cosine_of_c_float(9, 3, 7)

  Return angle(angle_c_float)
```

If it looks like a pile of nonsense that's because it is........

Comment: What's giving you trouble right now? Where do you need help?

Comment: Your syntax is terribly wrong. after a function def you should use : instead of =, and `return` is with lower case.

Answer (score 10):

You have a python problem and a math problem.

This code should do what you want:

```
import math

a = 3 
b = 7 
c = 9

def angle (a, b, c):
    return math.degrees(math.acos((c**2 - b**2 - a**2)/(-2.0 * a * b)))

angA = angle(a,b,c)
angB = angle(b,c,a)
angC = angle(c,a,b)

assert angA + angB + angC == 180.0

print angA
print angB
print angC
```

Explanations: your homework wants you to calculate the angle for each or the three corners. This is done by the formula, and the three angles should sum up to 180, as every triangle do. What I did is to create a function, which takes in degrees the acosine of each angle (the function considers the order of the arguments) and then created the assertion and printed the results.

An important point is that you entered your numbers as integers (3, 7, 9), and there is a division in the formula. This is an integer division since everything in denominator and numerator are integers. So I used `2.0` to tell Python that this two is a floating point number, and everything else is then converted automatically. This is somewhat subtle, and you should pay attention to that.

Hope this helps, and don't give up studying, either Python and Math!

Comment: You my friend are a God send thankyou very much!!!!!! I just need more practice with this stuff. Interestingly when you break it down like this it makes so much more sense; and no I wont give up!!!! Thanks for the encouragement man!

Comment: This doesn't return the correct results if the side lengths are `a=3, b=4, c=5`

Comment: @acollection_ I have ran the code with these values and didn't have an assertion error. Also, for the record, the printed values were 90.0, 
36.8698976458 and 53.1301023542

Comment: I may have written my code wrong. Either way, I can't remember what I ended up doing. Thanks for the reply!